# How can I disable the Terminal Emulator for certain users?

Tags: security, users, gnome-terminal

How to prevent specific users from using the terminal emulator?!

I make a trick by writing a script in `.bashrc` which request a user to enter a password to be able to use the terminal emulator.

But this trick is not the perfect method for some advanced users who knows how to work over this trick.

For that, I'm seeking a method to prevent specific users from using terminal emulator at all, those users are just normal users without `sudo` permission.

Any suggestions?!

Comment: The one who have downvoted.. It's better to say why?!

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to disable the terminal for certain users?

Comment: I disagree with the downvote. Some users should not be allowed to use terminal commands :+

Comment: @R110 You have to forbid some users from using terminal since at least in my case many of them will mess up with the system or files or whatever. Anyway, it's a need for me even you don't think so... But i just ask who have downvoted just to say why?!

Answer (score 3):

Create a group for users allowed to use terminals, let's say `terminalusers`. Find the terminal program (use `which`), for example, `xterm`. Change its ownership accordingly :

```
chown root:terminalusers /usr/bin/xterm
```

Allow execution for the owner, and the group. Deny for others :

```
chmod 750 /usr/bin/xterm
```

At this point, using `xterm` wont be possible unless you're root, or a member of the `terminalusers` group (add yourself to it, and you'll be able to use `xterm`). Apply similar settings for other terminal emulators (`gnome-terminal` is your main one I suppose). Now, this is just another *trick* : it blocks terminal emulators, not terminals (subtle difference indeed).

In a UNIX environment, terminals are the primary interfaces to the system. Blocking them is very likely to disturb many applications, not only command-line ones. Blocking terminal emulators instead is nothing but a workaround. With good permissions, remember that nothing bad can happen to your machine from a user terminal : it takes root privileges to mess things up.

*Note* : with `xterm`, this is said to cause problems with `utmp`.

Comment: I know the difference between my friend. It's just a bad habit in naming things rapidly.. Thanks for your suggestion. I'll wait a little bit more for answers if there is no better i'll not forget to mark it as answer

Comment: Just in case it isn't obvious, changing a few /usr/bin/foo permissions won't stop a terminal emulator installed under ~/bin/ ...

Comment: It might me difficult to `./configure && make && make install` a custom terminal without... a terminal. Blocking terminals isn't "normal" in a UNIX environment, it'll always be about workarounds...

Answer (score 1):

Especially if your "targeted" user has no `sudo` privileges, the solution below is pretty "waterproof". It can be used not only to block users from the terminal, but (*any* user) from using *any* application.

#### What it is

The solution exists of a simple and very light-weight background script that you can use in a flexible way to block users from applications. 
The script is started on start up from `/etc/rc.local` (see further below)

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time

data = [
    ["jacob", "gedit", "thunderbird", "gnome-terminal"],
    ["William", "gedit"],
    ]

def user_appcheck(userdata):
    try:
        user = userdata[0]; apps = userdata[1:]
        applist = subprocess.check_output(["ps", "-u", user]).decode("utf-8").splitlines()
        matches = sum([[l.split()[-1] for l in applist if app in l] for app in apps], [])
        for match in matches:
            subprocess.Popen(["pkill", match])
    except:
        pass

while True:
    for userdata in data:
        user_appcheck(userdata)
    time.sleep(4)
```

#### How to use

1. copy the script below into an empty file, save it as `users_apps.py` in a location where "normal" users cannot edit the file.
2. In the head section of the script, set the user(s) and their blocked applications in the format:

   ```
   ["<username>", "<application>"],
   ```

For a single user, blocking `gedit` and `gnome-terminal` e.g.

```
    data = [
        ["jacob", "gedit", "gnome-terminal"],
        ]
```

3. Add a line to `/etc/rc.local`:

   ```
   /bin/bash -c "python3 /path/to/users_apps.py&"
   ```
4. Test-run it by running `/etc/rc.local` 
   **NB** test it with a non- essential application from your user account:

   ```
   /etc/rc.local
   ```

   If you blocked yourself, you shouldn't be able to run the application; it might just open in a flash, but will close immediately.

There is not much to be done about it if a user does not have `sudo` permissions :)

Comment: @Maythux could you give some feedback? did you try it, is this (the kind of) solution you are looking for?